# Simple way to prevent duplicate logging of errors

Tags: c#, multithreading, error-handling

I've been tasked with updating our current error logging system to prevent the logging of similar errors (from a single client program) that were probably caused by the same event. The code here is what I have added in order to accomplish this. Are there any obvious issues I am missing or is there a simpler way to accomplish this? I need to deal with multiple threads.

Here is the simple error object we use:

```
public class ErrorObject
{
    //to use when sending an object to a background worker
    public ErrorObject(Exception exception, string additionalinfo,DateTime? dateTime = null,bool showTouser = false)
    {
        Exception = exception;
        AdditionalInfo = additionalinfo;
        Time = dateTime ?? DateTime.Now;
    }

    public Exception Exception { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public bool ShownToUser { get; set; }
}
```

Other code calls this function to log errors.

```
public static Int32 LogError(Exception ex, bool runInBackground = true, string additionalInfo = "",
    bool ShownToUser = false)
{

    int retVal = -1;
    if (runInBackground)
    {
        ErrorObject newError = new ErrorObject(ex,additionalInfo,DateTime.Now,ShownToUser);

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(LogErrorInBackground, newError);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {   //Do a Sql Insert in current thread (slow for remote labs...)
            retVal = InsertError(ex, additionalInfo, ShownToUser);
        }
        catch{}
    }
    return retVal;
}


//Store 4 previous errors to compare against
private static Queue<ErrorObject> PreviousErrors = new Queue<ErrorObject>(4);
private static object PreviousErrorLock = new object();

private static void LogErrorInBackground(object state)
{
    ErrorObject error = (ErrorObject) state;

    if (! QueueNewError(error))
    {
        InsertError(error.Exception, error.AdditionalInfo, error.ShownToUser);
    }
}


/// <summary>Adds an error to the PreviousErrors Queue and removes the error at the front of the list.</summary>
/// <returns>Returns true if the error is a duplicate of any other previous errors in the queue.</returns>
private static bool QueueNewError(ErrorObject newError)
{
    //Assume the new error is not a duplicate
    bool isDuplicate = false;

    lock (PreviousErrorLock)
    {

        foreach (ErrorObject previousError in PreviousErrors)
        {
            if (previousError.AdditionalInfo == newError.AdditionalInfo &&
            Math.Abs((previousError.Time - newError.Time).TotalSeconds) < 3 &&
            previousError.Exception.GetType() == newError.Exception.GetType() &&
            previousError.Exception.Message == newError.Exception.Message &&
            previousError.Exception.TargetSite == newError.Exception.TargetSite)
            {
                isDuplicate = true;
                break;//Exit the loop
            }
        }

        if( PreviousErrors.Count > 0)
            PreviousErrors.Dequeue();
        PreviousErrors.Enqueue(new ErrorObject(newError.Exception, newError.AdditionalInfo, newError.Time));
    }
    return isDuplicate;
}
```

Comment: After more testing I found that i'm not recording 4 most recent errors I need to adjust the Dequeue() operation to be             `if( PreviousErrors.Count > 3) PreviousErrors.Dequeue();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ErrorObject newError = new ErrorObject(…);
```

This is one of the cases where most people will probably agree that you can use `var` here. Doing that doesn't lose any information (you can still see at a glance that `newError` is an `ErrorObject`) and it makes the code shorter and more DRY.

---

```
return retVal;
```

In general, you shouldn't use integer `retVal`s. If you need to report errors, use exceptions. If you want to report success or failure, use a `bool`. If you want to report multiple possible results, use an `enum`. If you want to report some kind of count (though I don't see how would that make sense here), at least name your variable something like `count`, not `retVal`.

---

```
//Store 4 previous errors to compare against
private static Queue<ErrorObject> PreviousErrors = new Queue<ErrorObject>(4);
```

This sounds like a job for a simple reusable custom collection. Something like:

```
class BoundedQueue<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly int count;
    private readonly Queue<T> queue;

    public BoundedQueue(int count)
    {
        this.count = count;
        this.queue = new Queue<T>(count);
    }

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        if (queue.Count == count)
            queue.Dequeue();

        queue.Enqueue(item);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return queue.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

---

```
lock (PreviousErrorLock)
```

Since you want to lock access to the `PreviousErrors` object, you should use that in the lock, you don't need another object for this. (An object used just for locking makes sense when you logically want to do something like `lock (this)`, but that's not the case here.)

---

```
foreach (ErrorObject previousError in PreviousErrors)
{
    if (previousError.AdditionalInfo == newError.AdditionalInfo &&
    Math.Abs((previousError.Time - newError.Time).TotalSeconds) < 3 &&
    previousError.Exception.GetType() == newError.Exception.GetType() &&
    previousError.Exception.Message == newError.Exception.Message &&
    previousError.Exception.TargetSite == newError.Exception.TargetSite)
    {
        isDuplicate = true;
        break;//Exit the loop
    }
}
```

You should extract this equality testing code into a separate method, possibly as `ErrorObject.Equals()`. With that, this code would simplify to:

```
bool isDuplicate = PreviousErrors.Contains(newError);
```

---

```
break;//Exit the loop
```

You don't need this comment. Everyone knows what `break` does inside a loop.

---

Also, I find the queue logic suspicious: when you detect a duplicate, you add it to the queue anyway. So if the sequence of exceptions is something like 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, then you're going to report 1 twice, even though it's among the 2 most recent error kinds.

Comment: In reference to the Queue logic. The thought was that if the same 'type' of error is separated by several others, then it could potentially be from a different Exception event and we would want to capture it.